# JQuery - Pop up to appear over parent span

Tags: jquery, css

All-

I started creating my own custom "pop up" which basically appears over the parent span until data is entered, and then it closes once you hit save (like most pop ups). This is what I was doing:

```
o.click(function(e)
{
    var editor = $(this).find(".object_editor");

    // we want to display it over our parent
    var offset = $(this).parent().offset();
    editor.css('left',offset.left);    
    editor.css('top',offset.top);

    editor.css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Instead of rolling my own solution, is there something that exists already that I should be using? Like boxy or qTip. I haven't found the ability to set the position of the windows that appear with these solutions.

Thanks!
~ Josh

Comment: Try jQuery SimpleModal : http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: I have used qTip extensively on a variety of projects, and would highly recommend it for ease of use as well as customization and performance.

Answer (score 0):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

"Add small overlays of content, like those on the iPad, to any element for housing secondary information. Hover over the button to trigger the popover. Requires Tooltip to be included."

Comment: Yea I actually tried to use bootstrap but it completely changed the design of my website when I tried to use it :/

Comment: You don't have to use the entire library. Just grab bootstrap-tooltip.js, bootstrap-popover.js, and the relevant styles from bootstrap.css.